# Check that my inputed text string in a field is correct filled using Selenium Python Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver, assert

Imagine situation that I want assert or verify any text field. I type any my text into a field using the script and that i want to verify / assert itself whether its correct filled in proper place.

I have tried funcion "contains text", but what to do if its not appeared in code e. g. the text string like some text.

Actually works for pre defined text strings in code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Sample text")]').text

assert element.strip() == "Sample Text"
```

Comment: Please, have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then edit the question and share what you have tried (code) and a reproductible example.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML.

Comment: https://boxing-registration.herokuapp.com/

Comment: e.g. I write my name and then i need to check it e. g. by assert function

Answer (score 0):

To enter value and assert induce `webdriverwait` and `get_attribute("value")`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://boxing-registration.herokuapp.com/")
nameval="Luke Teensie"
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#name-input"))).send_keys(nameval)
returnval=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#name-input"))).get_attribute("value")
assert returnval == nameval
```

---

Updated with XPATH.

---

```
driver.get("https://boxing-registration.herokuapp.com/")
nameval="Luke Teensie"
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='name-input']"))).send_keys(nameval)
returnval=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='name-input']"))).get_attribute("value")
assert returnval == nameval
```

Comment: can i go through xpath and can i use python syntax?

Comment: Yes you can use xpath as well.Check updated with xpath option.Let me know the status?

Comment: I have put it into my answer.

Comment: @LukeTeensie : You shouldn't use sleep instead use `WebDriverWait` what I have suggested.